# Hiding a column in a matrix if it is null

Tags: report, rdlc

Is there a way to hide a matrix column when its value is null? i have searched the web and I found out that I can go to the column properties -> visibility and hide it through an expression:

```
=iif(Fields!yourColumn.Value=="",true,false)
```

But whenever I try to put this on, it gives me the error below:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks guys.